# Check height of loaded page using AJAX and Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have trying to check the height of a loaded page using Ajax and Jquery, here is my code:

```
                        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            success: function(msg){ 
                                var heigOfDiv = html(msg).height();
                                alert (heigOfDiv);
                            }
                        });
```

**i.e.** If a load page `example.php` and the `height of this page is 2500px` I want to alert this number.
I tried with `document.height()` but does give me the height of the actual page. 
Any ideas how to do this? I need to calculate the height because I want to use a jquery scrollbar and the height to assign it to the viewport.

Comment: If you want to calculate the height at first elements should be added to the DOM.

Comment: Basically I have to load it and once is in the DOM I can check height?

Comment: Yes, then you can check the height, but if there are images in returned markup, you should listen to the `load` method.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to append the element do the DOM, so the browser would render the element and to generate it's dimensions. I would do this by appending it do a hidden container (via `visibility:hidden`, and not `display:none`) of 1x1px, with `overflow:hidden` so it would not affect the current page dimension, and then measure it's height via jQuery.